# How can I calculate the percentage of occurrences of a value in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

I have a query which puts data into a temporary table, with fields:

```
nRating INT
agentId INT
agent VARCHAR(50)
```

A rating value can either be 0 representing 'no', or 1 representing 'yes'. Without using a temporary table, what is the best way to calculate the percentage of yes and percentage of no ratings for each agent?

We are using MSSQL 2014.

Comment: Instead of worrying about "the best way", why don't you try and write this query yourself first, and if its impractical, inefficient, or problematic in some fashion, show us that attempt, so we can help you with your specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `avg()`.  In some databases:

```
select agentId, avg(rating) as yes_ratio, avg(1 - rating) as no_ratio
from temptable t
group by agentid;
```

Some databases do integer arithmetic (notably SQL Server), so you want a non-integer numeric.  I often do this  just by multiplying by 1.0:

```
select agentId, avg(rating*1.0) as yes_ratio, avg(1.0 - rating) as no_ratio
from temptable t
group by agentid;
```

You can also do that by doing `cast(rating as float)`.

Comment: Great idea. Just a note - the second one does what OP needs. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93558/8). Of course, depending on how they're using it, they may also need to multiply this average by 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    AgentId, 
    Agent,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B = 0 THEN 1.00 ELSE 0.00 END) / COUNT(*) AS NEG, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN 1.00 ELSE 0.00 END) / COUNT(*)  AS POS
FROM
    YOURTABLE
GROUP BY
    AgentId, 
    Agent
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just think about how you would normally calculate a percentage. You would take the number of times it occurs, over the total number of records, and multiply by 100.

So, it could look something like this:

```
SELECT (SUM(nRating) * 100 / COUNT(*)) AS percentageOfYesRatings
FROM agentTable
GROUP BY agentId;
```

**A Side Note**

A special thing to note here is that SUM() only works here because the nRating will be 1. What you are *really* doing is getting the number of times that they got a rating of 1. It's important to remember this in the future, because if you did this example where say the rating could be between 0 and 5 and you wanted to get the percentage of positive ratings, the query would look a little different.

In fact, it might look something like this, which is what you need to do to get the percentage of no ratings:

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN nRating = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(*)) AS percentageOfNoRatings
FROM agentTable
GROUP BY agentId;
```

This is instead counting the number of occurences of a 0 rating. To do both you can just combine the query. Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93558/3).